# Does Windows support PEAPv1/EAP-GTC?

Tags: wifi, peap

We are running a wireless infrastructure using PEAPv1/EAP-GTC. Our Windows machines can't seem to connect to wireless access points, what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naitvely, Windows does not support PEAP-GTC, however there are supplicants available to support PEAP-GTC authentication on Windows.